# Speech.Recognition GrammarBuilder/Choices Tree Structure

Tags: c#, tree, speech-recognition, text-to-speech

In playing around with C#'s Speech Recognition, I've stumbled across a road block in the creation of an effective GrammerBuilder with Choices (more specifically, Choices of Choices).

IE considering the following logical commands.

[image]

One solution would to "hard code" every combination of Speech lines and add them to a GrammarBuilder (ie "SET LEFT COLOR RED" and "SET RIGHT CLEAR", however, this would quickly max out the limit of 1024, especially when dealing with number combinations.

Another solution would to Append all 'columns' as "Choices" (and filter out incorrect paths upon 'recognition', however this seems like it's processor heavy and unnecessary.

The middle ground, seems like the best path - with Choices of Choices - like a tree structure on a GrammarBuilder - however I'm not sure how to proceed.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you may need to include more information about how the speech-recognition library you're using works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build a `Choices` object from a set of `GrammarBuilder` objects using the [`Choices.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576557%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
  // Create alternatives for female names and add a phrase.
  GrammarBuilder females = new Choices(new string[] { "Anne", "Mary" });
  females.Append("on her");

  // Create alternatives for male names and add a phrase.
  GrammarBuilder males = new Choices(new string[] { "James", "Sam" });
  males.Append("on his");

  // Create a Choices object that contains an array of alternative
  // GrammarBuilder objects.
  Choices people = new Choices();
  people.Add(new Choices(new GrammarBuilder[] {females, males}));

  // Create a Choices object that contains a set of alternative phone types.
  Choices phoneType = new Choices();
  phoneType.Add(new string[] { "cell", "home", "work" });

  // Construct the phrase.
  GrammarBuilder gb = new GrammarBuilder();
  gb.Append("call");
  gb.Append(people);
  gb.Append(phoneType);
  gb.Append(new GrammarBuilder("phone"), 0, 1);
```

This lets you easily build a tree of choices.

Note that you may well want to add[`SemanticResultValues`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.semanticresultvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on each branch of the `Choice` and [`SemanticResultKeys`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.semanticresultkey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) at each level of `Choice` so that you don't have to reparse the text after recognition.

Answer (score -1):

Work backwards appending grammarbuilder objects as opposed to choices objects.  The choices object should only be used for the final tree options (red, blue) & (black, white).